# How to transfer a binary search tree to an increasing order search?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This is a question from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/increasing-order-search-tree/).
It says

> Given the root of a binary search tree, rearrange the tree in
> in-order so that the leftmost node in the tree is now the root of the
> tree, and every node has no left child and only one right child.

Example 1,
[image]

Example 2,

[image]

My code is almost the same as below,

```
void inorder(struct TreeNode *root, struct TreeNode **newRoot)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    inorder(root->left, newRoot);
    (*newRoot)->left = NULL;
    (*newRoot)->right = root;
    *newRoot = (*newRoot)->right;
    inorder(root->right, newRoot);
    return;
}

struct TreeNode* increasingBST(struct TreeNode *root)
{
    struct TreeNode *newRoot = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    struct TreeNode *result = newRoot;
    inorder(root, &newRoot);
    //newRoot->left = NULL;
    //newRoot->right = NULL;
    return result->right;
}
```

It worked well with several inputs until the input, [2,1,4,null,null,3].
Actually, it returned in the end but I still got "Time Limit Exceeded" error.
I found there is a similar solution but it activates two lines above,

```
newRoot->left = NULL;
newRoot->right = NULL;
```

Then it works.
I don't get how come this two lines are that critical.
Please shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the algorithm you have posted doing two things one after the another.

- First it traverse the tree in INORDER manner
- Second, it appends the visited node at the right node of current node and making the left node disable (assigning it NULL)

Now the following code snippet doing most import thing of your tree:

```
newRoot->left = NULL;
newRoot->right = NULL;
```

It is marking the boundary of the tree. For a second, just assume, if you not mark your boundary (by not using the snippet above), you are always in the tree, in other words you are not come out from the tree.

Though, you not posted data-structure of the tree, I can assume, left and right child is not setting to NULL when the value was assigned.